# Downloading files on background

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it allowed to download files on background with a background process? I know there is a limitation that it is allowed to run only every 15 minutes or so but are there any other limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Background Agent. This [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29) helps explain what can and cannot be done within a Background Agent. You'll need to choose between a PeriodicTask, and a ResourceIntensiveTask depending on how much needs to be done.

Comment: But is it possible to download files if I use Periodic Agent?

Comment: Yes. The key is to call NotifyComplete() after your download. There are many limitations within a Periodic Agent. It's best to read the article.